# If it quacks like an abelian variety over a finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Consider smooth projective varieties over a finite field. If a curve "looks like" an elliptic curve (i.e. has genus $1$) then it can be made into an elliptic curve.

Is there something similar in higher dimensions, i.e. if we fix the values of some invariants can we guarantee that the variety admits an algebraic group structure? What is sufficient for threefolds?

Comment: Ah yeah, right, my bad. I messed up my Hasse-Weil bound :P

Comment: @Wojowu There is actually a much easier proof that every genus 1 curve over a finite field has a point, and it generalizes to the statement that if $F$ Is a finite field and $A/F$ is a variety such that $A/\overline{F}$ is an abelian variety, then $A(F)\ne\emptyset$, so $A/F$ is itself already an abelian variety. (I have a recollection this may be due to Lang, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: Have you considered the dimension 2 case? Clearly a necessary condition is that the Kodaira dimension be 0. There are just a few such classes of varieties, so you can check to see whether their discrete invariants suffice to pick out the abelian surfaces.

Comment: @JoeSilverman the classification of surfaces in positive characteristic is kind of confusing to me but I tried. In higher dimensions I don't know anything

Comment: I don't know about finite fields, but over $\mathbb C$ by https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903184 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011042, if $h^0(2K_X)=1$ and $h^0(\Omega ^1_X)=\dim X$, then $X$ is birational to an abelian variety. If $k$ is an algebraically closed field of char $p>0$, then related results are contained in https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06631.

Comment: Sommese, Quaternion Manifolds (1975) https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01357140 constructed a complex 3-fold which is diffeomorphic to $(S^1)^6$ but not a complex torus. So there is grounds for caution. I found a readable description of the construction in the first pages of https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1291041217

Comment: Okay, I read further in the Catanese et al paper, and I retract my warning. According to Theorem 2.3, if $X$ is a compact complex manifold which (1) has the integer cohomology ring of a torus and (2) is bimeromorphic to a compact Kahler manifold, then $X$ is a complex torus. In particular, if (1) holds and $X$ is algebraic then Chow's lemma tells us it is  birational to a projective variety, so this should show it is an abelian variety. That doesn't prove anything in char p, but it means that I no longer consider this a reason for caution.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, a funny business! Thanks for the illuminating points, even if not exactly annihilating the original question.

Comment: Perhaps if the integral $\ell$-adic cohomology ring looks like the cohomology of an abelian variety for all $\ell$, including crystalline cohomology if $\ell=p$? This could suffice to show that the Albanese map has degree $1$ (by pulling back cohomology classes in $H^1$ from the Albanese and then cupping them to degree $2n$ to calculate the degree) and that it is finite (because the class of any curve that is contracted by the map would have zero cup product with any $2n-1$ classes in degree $1$) which would imply it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 8):

One possible answer to this could be [Lang's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang%27s_theorem): it says that if $G/\mathbb{F}_q$ is a smooth connected algebraic group, then $H^1(\mathbb{F}_q,G)$ is trivial, or otherwise put every $G$-torsor has an $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational point.
This generalizes your example: if $X/\mathbb{F}_q$ is a smooth projective variety such that $X_{\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q}$ is isomorphic to an abelian variety, then $X$ is a torsor under its Albanese variety $A = Alb(X)$.
If $X$ has dimension $1$ then requiring the genus of $X$ to be $1$ is enough.
If $X$ has dimension $2$ then by the classification of surfaces it is enough to assume that e.g. the canonical bundle of $X$ is trivial and $X$ is not simply connected.

Edit: as pointed out below, the previous sentence is correct only if the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $\neq 2,3$. If we additionally assume that the second $l$-adic Betti number equals $6$, then we get a criterion in all characteristics.

Comment: the last sentence is incorrect. One can take $X$ to be a non-classical Enriques surface in characteristic $2$ https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05198